# How to call a SAP Fiori tile whose app type is SAP GUI with parameters?

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I am trying to implement cross app navigation to this app: [KB16N](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('KB16N')/S12OP) but with parameters like the Company Code and Document Number.

In the Fiori Apps Library, there are no additional parameters mentioned in the Configuration section. The technical information for the 2 parameters I want to pass is as below:
[image: Cost Center]
[image: Document Number]

As per my understanding, we can add parameters while Tile Configuration in Launchpad Designer. And then I would use this parameter in my cross app navigation code in SAPUI5 app. But to add parameters, how to get the 'Target Name' value highlighted below:

[image]

Kindly assist.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of `KB16N` and indicate the fields you're interested in filling a value (?), I don't see neither the Company Code nor the Reference Document Number.

Comment: @SandraRossi I've added information about the fields I am looking to pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `F1` on the input of the screen,

1. Check the `Parameter ID`, for example, for ControllingArea, it is `CAC`. the **Target Name** is `CAC`.
2. Or Check the table name and field name. For example, the Controlling Area of KB16N, the **Target Name** is `TKA01-KOKRS`.

btw, I am not familiar with KB16N, i cannot find the CompanyCode and ReferenceDocumentNumber in the screens.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did F1 on those fields and got the above attached technical information about them. Now, I need to know if I will add the 'Field Name' in the parameter section's 'Target Name' in the Launchpad Designer. And then will I mention these parameter names in the cross app navigation section?

Comment: Yes. You need to maintain the target mapping, for example,  between Name(ControllingArea) and Target Name(TKA01-KOKRS). even you can maintain a default value from user setting %%UserDefault.extended.ControllingArea%% . Of course, you need to supply the parameter like ControllingArea = A001 in the navigation.

Comment: I maintained the target mapping accordingly and included this in the navigation code. But now when it is navigated, it shows a message "Fill out all required entry fields" and a pop-up for selection of the controlling area is still being shown.

Comment: @d33a please use CAC, i did a prototype and it works well.